# What is the jerk parameter in terms of the Density parameters and equation of state?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, density, jerk

In cosmology the deceleration parameter defined as the

$$q_0 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_i\Omega_{i,0}(1+3w_i)$$

Is there a similar expression for the jerk parameter ($j_0$)?

Comment: Do you understand the derivation of that expression for $q_0$? If so, what prevents you from extending that derivation to find $j_0$?

Comment: You should not consider your expression for $q_0$ to be its *definition*.

Answer (score 1):

In general

$$j(q) = q + 2q^2 + (1+z)\frac{dq}{dz}$$

and

$$j_0 = q_0 + 2q_0^2 + \left. \frac{dq}{dz} \right|_{z=0}$$